# Why does inductor core saturation depend on the temperature?

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism, inductance, magnetics, magnetic-flux

For example at room temperature (20ºC) the saturation current is 450mA and with 100ºC the saturation current is 350mA. What causes this?

(Edit) The higher inductance with higher temperatures and lower currents is my biggest question here.

This is a graph for a power inductor. The original video is here: [Temperature influence of the saturation current for an inductor](https://passive-components.eu/temperature-influence-of-the-saturation-current-for-an-inductor/)

[image: Saturation Current and temperature]

Comment: Magnetic properties of materials causes that, [this](https://unlcms.unl.edu/cas/physics/tsymbal/teaching/SSP-927/Section%2016_Magnetic_Properties_2.pdf) has details.

Comment: @jay Interesting catch for temperatures well below the curie temperature of a material -- spin waves! (And the Bloch law.) Thanks. I still have to absorb the new model, though, to see if it predicts the OP's presented curves or if something else is also needed.

Comment: @jay can you explain it to him in 25 words or less?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 , I'd like to give you a chance to finish it in less than 10 words.

Comment: I can't give you a good answer. But in my experience EVERYTHING depends on temperature. It is very rare to find something that does not grow or shrink or speed up or slow down or increase or decrease with temperature. Most things which are not sensitive to temperature have been specifically designed to have that property.

Comment: @jay thanks for your generous offer.  ;)  My Electromagnetics Prof Dr. Wolfgang Borner, in 1974 filled up 10 blackboards with equations every class.. He back then predicted we would have electroluminescent walls with images (True with OLEDs or my wall of LED backlit TV leg's length away) and Radar that could see around mountains from refraction (not quite) but I have been thinking of an invisible police RADAR zapper so I can request calibration on the spot. :);)

Comment: Maybe it helps to slightly rephrase the plot axes: Current through the inductor coil is essentially the magnetic field H and inductance is essentially the permeability or dM/dH. So your plot gives dM/dH vs H or in other words: it shows the derivative of the hysteresis curve. In the comments of @MarcusMüller answer, it is explained why this curve gets narrower at higher temperature.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, I have answered it in 5 words. Probably Dr. Borner had reason to do that, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

This is mostly a solid-state physics question, but, to boil this down to something that we can answer without going into finesse of core material physics:

Magnetism happens when in a material, you can align the spins of electrons around their core (or more generally, the spin normal of any charged quantum) – in "normal" materials, these are totally randomly oriented, and once you've aligned a lot of the spin axes to point in the same direction, you get a macroscopically observable effect "magnetism".

The ability of cores to store energy energy depends on the "alignability" of these spins.

The hotter any material, the more random the movement, positions and orientations of the atoms inside; so, heating up material actively works against its ability to store energy in a magnetic field.

This, however, doesn't explain the *opposite* observation you have. To clear things up a little, I'd like to preserve the comment discussion below here, credits to @jonk there:

> Domain walls are like soap bubble surfaces arranged to minimize energy. At low currents, the applied field mostly goes into modifying the walls so that the volume of bubbles that line up with the magnetic field grow much larger than the volume within the oppositely aligned bubbles. This is a smooth effect. But there is also a number of complications lumped together as Barkhausen and magnetostriction effects. Higher temperatures, at low magnetization currents, allow the bubble walls to snap more easily over these Barkhausen effect barriers.
>
> So the remaining vacuum path length (the physical path length minus the net bubble path lengths) is a little bit shorter resulting in a slightly higher inductance. At higher currents, most of the bubble walls have done all the moving they can do, as well as all of the lumped Barkhausen and magnetostriction effects, and now the effect of temperature is to reduce the net aligned bubble volume because of all the excess continual jostling (unsettling of existing aligned bubble volumes.) These two extreme ends explain the opposing behaviors.

@Tobalt argues

> At high temperatures, both magnetic exchange and magnetic anisotropy decrease. This leads to: a) reduced domain wall energy and b) increased domain wall width. Both lead to lower domain wall pinning, which in turn c) decreases coercivity d) increases the dM/dH, i.e. permeability

Helpfully, @jonk also links to the [Feynman lectures chapter](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_37.html) on magnetic materials. I'd like to cite one thing from that:

[image: Summary: Magnets are complicated. Good luck on the exam.]

Comment: There are some interesting details in the chart, Marcus. Note that the inductance is higher for high temperatures, at low currents, but this relative orientation flips over in saturation so that inductance is lower at high temps and higher currents. A simple, non-quantitiative interpretation of thermal agitation explains this behavior, as well. Can you expand your answer to address this aspect of the OPs chart?

Comment: @jonk I must admit that I couldn *not* with any degree of confidence in my wording; I'd rather you post that as an answer!

Comment: Domain walls are like soap bubble surfaces arranged to minimize energy. At low currents, the applied field mostly goes into modifying the walls so that the volume of bubbles that line up with the magnetic field grow much larger than the volume within the oppositely aligned bubbles. This is a smooth effect. But there is also a number of complications lumped together as Barkhausen and magnetostriction effects. Higher temperatures, at low magnetization currents, allow the bubble walls to snap more easily over these Barkhausen effect barriers.

Comment: So the remaining vacuum path length (the physical path length minus the net bubble path lengths) is a little bit shorter resulting in a slightly higher inductance. At higher currents, most of the bubble walls have done all the moving they can do, as well as all of the lumped Barkhausen and magnetostriction effects, and now the effect of temperature is to reduce the net aligned bubble volume because of all the excess continual jostling (unsettling of existing aligned bubble volumes.) These two extreme ends explain the opposing behaviors.

Comment: I second that this question pretty much belongs into solid state physics (with which the physics.SE unfortunately does not appear to be overly concerned with). Having worked long years in solid state phys I put forth that a good model of solid state magnetism has not been developed to date. there are countless models starting from Weiss, Stoner etc. and many more modern ones. None seems to hold for more than a fraction of situations and materials. So this general answer captures the essence well enough.

Comment: @jonk At high temperatures, both magnetic exchange and magnetic anisotropy decrease. This leads to: a) reduced domain wall energy and b) increased domain wall width. Both lead to lower domain wall pinning, which in turn c) decreases coercivity d) increases the dM/dH, i.e. permeability.

Comment: @tobalt Thanks. I tried to keep my written perspective highly simplified (which is all I have in my head about it, anyway.) [This chapter from Feynman's Lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_37.html) is where I got my perspective over 30 years ago when I first read it. Much, I'm sure, has happened since that time. If you have a good, more modern source that tries to hit a similar reading level to Feynman's Lecture series on this topic, I'd love to know what it is. Meanwhile, why not write something here. I think it would be helpful to some of us.

Comment: @jonk the notions of magnetic exchange stiffness and anisotropy far predates Feynman :) This simple model is still used extensively today because it can account for so many domain (wall) physics *without* diving into quantum physics. Exchange likes to keep neighboring spins parallel (or antiparallel for antiferromagnets and ferrimagnets) and anisotropy likes to orient spins along certain spatial directions (granular directions for example). The interplay stabilizes domains and domain walls of certain thickness.

Comment: How does that define the sharp knee in the Temperature curve ?

Comment: Thank you all, the thermal part was understood by me but you touched the main point that is the higher inductance at lower currents with higher temperatures. It is still not clear to me why for example the inductance at 20ºC doesn't rise with more current (temperature also rises and magnetic permeability) and then goes down in the current limit like in the graph. It is just stable and falls down in the limit.

Comment: yes different magnetic domains affected by PTC >NP0>NTC vs T changes the NP0 temp with current and temp and not the same for all materials e.g. cobalt doped ferrite, don't worry about what you can't control, just understand the datasheets to avoid disaster

Comment: I am just trying to understand the phenomenon behind this temperature, inductance and saturation current.

Answer (score 3):

At high temperatures, the thermal energy of the system is greater than the magnetic energy, EmJ. **The Curie Temperature where the different magnetic domains cancel, and the relative permeability drops towards zero.** and the energy stored cannot be increased so L collapse to zero, 0 not the magnetic flux.  There is a thermal-magnetic equilibrium at this temperature.  Heating up magnets to this temperature also demagnetizes.

In between absolute 0'K and the Curie Temp.,there exists a rate of change to temperature for any molecular magnetic domain structure that controls permeability \$\dfrac{\Delta M}{M}=k~  T^{\frac{3}2}~~~~~~~~~~\$  *[ref (31)](https://unlcms.unl.edu/cas/physics/tsymbal/teaching/SSP-927/Section%2016_Magnetic_Properties_2.pdf)*

Magnetic qualities of charged particles have a complex interaction of forces that are maximized at absolute zero, 0'K and have zero magnetism at the Curie Temperature.

**Air does not Saturate** (yet)

This does not occur in vacuum of material excited by a wire loop, and we can neglect air as well for this application.

Transformer steels (Cold-rolled-grain-oriented-steel CRGOS) are usually 1.2 T up to exotic 1.9T (Est) while an air gap in 7 Tesla MRI can suck a metal folding chair across a cafeteria room at speeds up 60 MPH.

*Anecdote from head of NRC (National Research Council of Canada) who reported to me in Winnipeg, on the capability of the world 1st non-magnetic (hydraulic) MRI for use in operating rooms*

Take-a deep breath

An electron moving around a fixed point has an angular momentum.
\$L=m_erv\$ which is also defined by the area and around a wire is excited by current per unit length.

The charged particles have a nuclear spin, like a spinning top that has a [precessed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession) orbit at a slower rate. This magnetic dipole moment produces magnetic flux and the magnetic force along the wire created by the electric charge flow rate or current.  The energy of each spinning top is also an absolute permeability, and the sum of all tops is the net permeability of the material. The moments have distinct spin angles, discovered by  Stern and Gerlach in 1922.

[image] [credit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:LucasVB/Gallery)

The rate of change of \$\mu_r\$ with temperature depends on the material type and gaps between magnetic particles and the ratio of insulation and conductive to the magnetic particles.   Microwave has a higher ratio conductive/insulator material that creates the necessary equal gaps in ferrite magnetic particles. \$\mu/\epsilon\$.

The result is the knee of the curve where \$\mu_r\$ drops 10% is often used for the inductance at rated current. Above this in power ferrite, the margin to critical thermal runaway is the key figure of merit allowing aging of materials.  This is where the rate of change of temperature rises above steady-state with a rapid loss of inductance and impedance as heat cannot be removed fast enough. This is because inductors are usually drive by switched voltage sources and cannot be switched with current sources unless actively sensed and limited.

**Other Henries**

Another odd fact is the domain walls of Quartz crystal (XTAL's as in oscillators) can have the equivalent inductance of more than 1 Henry, but the excellent insulation of Quartz  creates a piezo effect, electromagnetic resonant vibrations with a tiny femptofarad "motional" capacitance.  It cannot be saturated with current because between the domain walls values “Henry and fF” exists several kV, for a Xtal power with 10 uW that cannot be tapped. This is why Xtal powers are minuscule, as there is a breakdown voltage or flashover inside the crystal from molecular impurities.

### Other Interesting Fact

If you notice for temperatures above room the Tempco is very small PTC then switches to NTC (bad) above 350mA yet saturates -10% around 450 mA . This means if your RMS current exceeds this a bit, you will run up to 100'C and close to runaway failure. A feature I added to a Lambda 1U 180W supply for my design for reliability was to epoxy a thermistor to the Ferrite  XFMR to drive a small transistor to a LM317 to regulate the current in 2 fans in series off 48V, when it reached 50'C the fans started. At 60'C it would run at full RPM which would only happen in a 40'C ambient with my spoiler and plenum turbulent design so it never exceeds or even comes close to critical temperature.

**So for added reliability, include thermal ferrite sensing ** for current limiting or voltage regulation or temp controlled fans that normally don't need to run.

Comment: Good source @jay  Now imagine the magnetic forces of a black hole

Comment: Sorry but many things are odd (or wrong) with this post: 1) Curie temp doesn't say anythiung about permeability, infact it is not negligible at the Curie temp. 2) superconducting solenoid magnets dont have airgaps, which is the sole reason for their large stray field and tendency to attract things. Magnets with cores and air gaps are rather benign because they have large field only near the gap and cant attract things from large distance.

Comment: I disagree but, feel free to make corrections but 1) Mz = N (γ ̄h)^2*J(J+1)Bo/3kT  magnetization drops to a very low level where it cannot store any more energy, L=0 at Tc. 2) superconductors have a different equation for Mz and drops the latter parts, but not relevant here anyway.  3) MRI's like torroids leak a lot of flux like magnets, which also has nothing to do with the saturation property in this question.  This 7 Tesla MRI imploded the images of all the CRT's in 7 floors above when operated inside a temporary Faraday Cage. (!) R&D,  The key question is saturation vs T  IMHO @tobalt

Comment: Antiferromagnets even have a maximum of susceptibility at the ordering temperature. The susceptibility drops off by a power law beyond that (but never reaches zero). For ferromagnets, the high temp drop off is similar. This is all described by the Curie-Weiss-Law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie%E2%80%93Weiss_law

Answer (score 1):

Question:

> Why does inductor core saturation depend on the temperature?

Answer in 5 words:

> [**Permeability depends on the temperature**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)).

> In general, permeability is not a constant, as it can vary with the
> position in the medium, the frequency of the applied magnetic field,
> humidity, temperature, and other parameters.

---

Temperature Coefficient Of Magnetic Permeability from: [NIST Research Library archive](https://archive.org/details/temper121101915245245unse/page/8/mode/2up)

Corelation of magnetic field and current, [Ampere's law: B = f(u * I)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law)

[image]

Comment: is that linear PTC or not linear NTC temperature.  Everything! depends on temperature

Comment: +1 for Brevity -1 for vagueness. How about " \$\mu\$ drops by \$T^{3/2}\$"  4 words

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 , " Everything! depends on temperature" , 4 words, you beat me! You are always amazing. What else do you see?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 , Are you the one doing -1 on my answers, even for the accepted ones? Someone must be very upset to do that.

Comment: I get trolls like that always not I. Anyone with substance will explain a down vote

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 , Ok, up one for that answer. Someone is not playing professional. Trying to belittle everyone.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 , I have a good regards toward your hard work. Meantime, that you tried is "mue drops by one and one half of Tee", 9 Words. Congratulations you got it, less than 10 words. Your "Everything! depends on temperature" is more impressive, 4 WORDS!.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 , Gotta go. I have a job interview in 30 minutes. It is nice talking to you. And, we have built some trust, I guess.